# Can a single molecule break chemical equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium, theoretical-chemistry

If a system is in chemical equilibrium is it possible to put the system out of its current state by introducing **novel** substances not present in it whose behavior isn't analogous to the one of the substances already in the system and whose interactions can start new reactions unseen by the system till the moment the new substance is added? Can even a miniscule concentration of that substance (so miniscule it could be as small as even 1 molecule) start dramatic changes capable of affecting the entire system?

To be clearer I would like to show an example. Imagine there is a system of substances all of the reactions among which have already reached equilibrium rates and the concentrations of their reagents and products are stable. Then, we add extra reagent not present in the system until that moment capable of interaction with its components to form novel molecule which on its turn is able to further interact with the components of the system to form other novel molecule and it can further interact with components of the system and so on until a molecule so large is formed that it splinters into 2 molecules. However, each of these molecules is further able to interact with components of the system to produce a "new generation" of large molecules which when a certain limit is reached splinter into 2 whose properties, however, are identical to the 2 molecules already described, so in the end novel substances emerge able to dramatically shift the equilibrium in which the system was before their addition. Then, is this example possible proof of the ability of even a single molecule to start a chain of reactions able to shift chemical equilibriums and is it a proof there can be systems appearing to be in the state of equilibrium but actually able to undergo great changes if the **appropriate** molecules are added to them?

Basically, the purpose of my question is to ask (if it's even possible) to have a system which has reached a state of chemical equilibrium **stable in time** but which can be radically altered by a reagent not characteristic for it by even a minute concentrations of that reagent. A perfect example of my point is a sterile growth medium. By all means it's in state of chemical equilibrium. All possible reactions able to occur in it are already occurring with equal speeds of the forward and reverse reactions with concentrations of their reagents and products already in equilibrium. As such there is *nothing new* that can occur in the system if we rely **only** on the *natural* processes able to develop in it. However, if we add even 1 bacterium able to grow in the medium many new reactions will start to occur as a result of its metabolism and it can dramatically change the entire system bringing it out of the state it was able to occupy for extremely long periods of time without it. To my mind the growth medium *is* in a state of chemical equilibrium and there is no way to suddenly develop a bacterium on its own, therefore, our perception of chemical equilibrium entails us with a certain degree of **predictability** we prescribe to systems actually able to undergo drastic changes if the "right kind" of reagents are added to them even in extremely minute concentrations, even for extremely large systems. Is my interpretation of chemical equilibrium correct? Am I misunderstanding something here?

Furthermore, if it's correct does it means there are possible systems whose path of evolution can be entirely unpredictable but they could appear stable in time? What if the difference between their long-term stability and the myriads of unpredictable states they can occupy is a single molecule of complexity unable to be produced by the system itself? Does it mean, then, that chemical equilibrium alone isn't a measure of the possible states of the system but only an *approximation* to what is currently possible under certain physical conditions for a mixture of reagents? Then, does it means there is a "limit of opportunity" for any system in equilibrium defining what is possible for the system currently, but not all that is possible for it under the physical conditions it's in? Finally, does it means certain substances can change this "limit of opportunity" by generating novel compounds and starting novel reactions taking the system out of its current state without the need for addition of new reagents for the system? Is that possible for any known **chemical** (I'm referring to chemistry alone here and not mentioning any equilibrium changes induced by biological agents) systems and what are these examples?

I'm looking for both a system and a reagent capable of displaying such behavior to explain a quest of mine. I'm thinking about the possibility of the existence of "cascade reactions" able to dramatically change systems already in **stable**, e.g. equilibrium, state but the compound causing the initial reaction in the cascade shouldn't be native to the system and it shouldn't be able to produce it on its own. I'm thinking about the existence of limits to the reactions possible under certain conditions induced not by the conditions themselves but by the levels of complexity the products of the reactions currently occurring in the system can reach. I mean if the reagents are relatively simple substances combining to produce relatively simple products then the system can reach a level of complexity where all reactions are in equilibrium under the given conditions but not **all possible** reactions that these reagents could participate in have occurred. Then, if we add even a single molecule of novel substance with a higher degree of complexity than the ones in the system, could it trigger this "cascade" of reactions leading it to a higher degree of complexity than it used to have? What if in this new state of more complex chemistry we add 1 more molecule with even a higher degree of complexity? If we repeat the process over and over again how far can we get? Could we react a state where **the entire system itself can begin selfreplicating its complexity** and even **evolving** further complexity on its own without further outside intervention? If this is possible then the purpose of my question is to understand in what systems at what state what kind of molecule can trigger such transition? If it isn't possible I want to know why and at what level of complexity such a transition stops? Basically, I my motivation is to understand where is the border when biology and chemistry meet and **is concept of a break in chemical equilibrium triggered by even a miniscule amount of the "right" kind of complexity crucial to finding it?**

P.S. I hope now my question is clear enough to attract good answers and be unblocked.

Comment: Discussion moved to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66563/discussion-on-question-by-yordan-yordanov-can-a-single-molecule-break-chemical-e).  Please try to keep back and forth to a minimum, even when it's a productive exchange like this one was.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody cares about a single molecule, so let's say *"a very small quantity"* instead. Well, then the answer will be along the following lines:

1. Small influences produce small changes. In particular, that small addition will bring your system to a new equilibrium (another state, if you'd like), but it would be infinitesimally close to your initial one.
2. Alternatively, if one tiny droplet will make the system run out of control and finally end up somewhere pretty far from the initial state, this means *it was never in equilibrium in the first place*.
3. In this last case, in particular, the added droplet might not have been necessary. Sooner or later, a huge enough fluctuation would do the same.

As an example of a system in the *"seemingly, but not really stable"* state, think of those [effervescent tablets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effervescent_tablet). They just sit on the shelf and do nothing, but add a *very* tiny amount of water and see what happens.

---

To sum it up, out notion of stability is pretty solid. There very much **is** the state of stability for any system; it is the only one, and it can't be dramatically changed by addition of one molecule of anything. In some systems this state may be hard to reach, but that's another story.

So it goes.

Comment: What about a system where all reactions are in equilibriums between the forward and reverse reaction and then if we add just one molecule of some substance this can start a *chain reaction* of generation of novel substances which spin the system into a totally different state. Then was the initial system *not in equilibrium*? But then it had all of its reactions at equilibrium concentrations of reagents and products. If that was the case, then, do I missunderstand something about the concept of chemical equilibrium at the first place?

Comment: The other way to look at this is significant figures. The mass of a proton is known to about 13 parts per billion. I doubt that any equilibrium constant is known to that precision.

Comment: @Yordan If your system had _all_ reactions, then it would have the said chain reaction too, and the chain reaction would develop and carry the system away from that state. If it didn't have the chain reaction (despite its being theoretically possible), then the system was not in equilibrium.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, but how can it had this reaction if it didn't had the compound which started it? Do you infer all compounds that can be synthesized under certain conditions are synthesized under the said conditions irrespective of the complexity of interactions required to synthesize them? What if the synthesis of the compound that could change completely the system has such a low probability that it would take a system many times larger than the visible universe to wait for trillions of trillions of years to produce even a 1% of chance to create the change inducing molecule?

Comment: For all we can see the system *is* in equilibrium for all that time, but do you say that our perception is deceiving and system is actually not in equilibrium although all we can measure about it says it is? Are you saying then, that systems which *look stable* throughout time from our current perception of chemistry aren''t but are just like clockwork devises waiting for their chance to burst into a totally unpredictable states which we couldn't even imagine and we actually never see they turn into our real world? Is that the correct interpretation of the concept of chemical equilibrium,then?

Comment: I don't like the _"totally unpredictable states"_ part, for it negates the existence of chemical knowledge as such. You know, more than a few people have put more than a little effort into those predictions. Other than that, you are mostly right. A system may sit out of equilibrium for ages and never tell you a thing. Diamonds, for example, are like that. Then again: fluctuations. If a reaction can be triggered by a _single_ molecule, then it stands a decent chance of being triggered by a random fluctuation, without any extra molecule.

Comment: Can you than tell me what kind of *fluctuation* can turn an ocean of  glucose into a single fully formed Escherichia coli bacterium? Here is a perfect example of a system which **is stable** for all I can tell about chemical equilibrium but yet a single bacterium can dramatically change this system. I also am quite certain the state of the ocean of glucose forming an E. coli bacterium is *totally unpredictable* from what we know about the properties of glucose solutions but if you have any other suggestions I am willing to hear them. Please, correct me when I'm wrong

Comment: because if I'm not wrong in anything it seems like to me that virtually *any* chemical having some Gibs free energy can turn into a myriad of things? Does that mean all these chemicals just *look stable* but they aren't because to me this is something not very well fitting our observations?Am I correct or am I missing something out here?

Comment: A single bacterium is much, much greater than a single molecule. Also, an ocean of glucose solution is _not_ stable even without biological influence. Left in contact with air, it will show visible signs of oxidation in a matter of days, maybe weeks. Without air, the decay will take longer, but still nowhere near as long as human life. Have you ever seen old specimens of organic reagents in museums? All except alkanes have turned to black tar. **Crystalline** glucose might outlast us, but then again, it is no good for _E.coli_ either.

Comment: I have seen black tar digged up from specimens of old organic materials and I know it can reach a pretty stable for but then again there are some bacteria which can feed on it, so I guess, the system even in that *equilibrium* state has enough energy to support life. Plus, what is that black tar anyways? Can you **specify** its composition given only knowledge of its initial state or is the system capable of turning into a myriad of states? Is the black tar even in equilibrium or is it in some state which can't be exactly predicted so we only have a general notion what is going on it but we ca

Comment: can't predict it? Even if we are taking about organic materials if they are sterile (I agree that bacteria can dramatically change everything) we can't know exactly what our sample will turn into-so what is the state of *predictability* of our research then? Even swamp mud left in anaerobic conditions for millions of years (I guess it pretty **stable** then) still is a mesh of different reagents although there are no reactions occurring in it and we use it extensively as coal for heat generation.  Only graphite is stable but can we get there without the millions of year of Earth's heat?

Comment: Black tar is not at equilibrium, I think. As for predictability, it is somewhat limited. Like you said, there might be a myriad of possibilities.